# ReactJS/Firebase: onSnapshot returns empty array several times before array

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following that grabs the user record according to the ID.

```
const useItemsF = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("user")
      .where("id", "==", `${user.uid}`)
      .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        const listItemsUsers = snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
          id: doc.id,
          ...doc.data()
        }));
        setItems(listItemsUsers);
        setLoading(false);
        console.log(loading);
      });
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);
  return items;
};
```

I then return this using:

```
const ItemList = () => {
  const listItemF = useItemsF();
  console.log(listItemF);
}

export default ItemList;
```

The problem is, in the console log listItemF is empty several times before showing the full array. How do I grab this and return the result straight away (or at least wait until it has been collected)

One of the fields within the user collection is an image that is optional - and I have it show a default image but when they upload their own image I find it shows the default image temporarily and then loads in their own image after a few seconds ... I would like to avoid this if possible so it does not show the default image if they have uploaded their own.

Comment: That async call to a remote database will take a bit of time. You can't get rid of the delay.

Comment: Esp if you're waiting for the image to be uploaded to the user collection first. You'll probably want to instead optimistically render the image. That is, hold on to the file reference and render that while you're waiting for the snapshot listener to get called.

Comment: Any ideas on how I would do that?

Comment: Use the file itself until you can swap it out for the one from your db `<Image src={listItemF.image || optimisticImageSrc} />`

Comment: Or just add a spinner after the user starts the upload, and before the image is visible from the db.

Comment: I use this currently: {listItemF?.length && listItemF[0]?.userProfilePic?.userPicURL ? <img className="dashimage" src={listItemF[0]?.userProfilePic?.userPicURL} /> : ( <img className="dashimage" src="/default.jpg" /> )} .. it shows the default image quickly before showing the uploaded image

Comment: @windowsill Combined, your comments would make a good answer to the question, so consider posting it below too. 

Comment: This might help, https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects. Look for the `intentionally double-invoking` part, react renders a component 2x times in dev (strict) mode.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @windowsill, async call to a remote database will take a bit of time. You can't get rid of the delay. Especially, if you're waiting for the image to be uploaded to the user collection first. You'll probably want to instead optimistically render the image. That is, hold on to the file reference and render that while you're waiting for the snapshot listener to get called.

Use the file itself until you can swap it out for the one from your db `<Image src={listItemF.image || optimisticImageSrc} />`
Or just add a spinner after the user starts the upload, and before the image is visible from the db.